# Can I install cudnn for cuda version 11.2?

Tags: gpu, cudnn

There is no install that says cudnn for cuda 11.2 so I was wondering if that was even possible.

Comment: CUDA 11.2 was released two weeks ago. There is not yet an accompanying CUDNN release. You need either CUDA 11.1, 11.0, 10.2 or 10.1 to use the current release of CUDNN at the time of writing

Comment: Thanks! That's what I assumed but just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cuDNN Release 8.1.0 has just been made available, in case you are still interested.

https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/release-notes/rel_8.html#rel-810

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Follow the installation instructions as per the guide here: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide, but ignore the version suggestion in the guide. Use any of the `libcudnn` versions as listed here that's compatible with CUDA v11.2: https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/